# Cannot get selectors right for CSS to set rule to achieve desired result

Tags: css

Here are some code fragments. I have a banner and I am changing its' size depending on whether it is the home page or other pages. 
HTML:

```
<div id="page1">
<header class=large_banner> <a class="logo" title="Swordsmen Martial Arts" href=""><span>Swordsmen Martial Arts</span></a>
    <div  id="myBanner" class="hero">
        <h1>We know Martial Arts</h1>
        <a class="btn" title="Get training from Masters"  href="http://hdkumdo.com/smen/about">Get training<span> from leading Masters</span></a>
    </div> ...
```

CSS

```
header div.hero {
    position: absolute;
    width: 42%;
    top: 99px;      
    left: 55%
}
header div.hero h1 {
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    color: #fff;
}

.large_banner {
height: 300px;     /* default height for Home page is 200px*/
};
```

The banner size component works fine and I get the correct size according to the page. My problem is that I also want to change the top property of the div hero so that it is more centrally aligned (between top and bottom) within the overall banner.
I have tried different combinations of class hero, large_banner and id myBanner with no success.

Comment: Your desired result is not clear for me.

Comment: Thank you. As much as anything, I am trying to understand/learn CSS. My understanding is that I should be able to specify 2 classes (.large_banner and .hero) then set a property. eg .large_banner.hero {top:120px;} but it appears to do nothing. I have tried various combinations of space and order to no avail. Also tried adding an ID but also without luck. So should it work? If so, how?

Comment: The example I cite above came from https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/ unless I misunderstood the article.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex`. Put the `.hero` in a container and give container css like in example: where `100vh` is window height and `34px` is Logo height

```css
#myBanner {
  height: calc(100vh - 34px);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.hero {
  margin-top: -34px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page1">
  <header class=large_banner>
    <a class="logo" title="Swordsmen Martial Arts" href="">
      <span>Swordsmen Martial Arts</span>
    </a>
    <div id="myBanner">
      <div class="hero">
        <h1>We know Martial Arts</h1>
        <a class="btn" title="Get training from Masters" href="http://hdkumdo.com/smen/about">Get training<span> from leading Masters</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```